# Custom Property

Tags: c#, properties

I´m working with windowsapps, and I need to do something different here. I created an object, with some custom properties using ICustomTypeDescriptor with some samples i found on the internet.

Here is my code:

```
class ObjectWithProperties : ICustomTypeDescriptor
{
    **public int MyProperty { get; set; }**

    class MyDescriptor : PropertyDescriptor
    {
        public MyDescriptor(string name, Attribute[] attributes) :
            base(name, attributes)
        {

        }

        public override bool CanResetValue(object component)
        {
            return true;
        }

        public override Type ComponentType
        {
            get { return typeof(ObjectWithProperties); }
        }

        public override object GetValue(object component)
        {
            return (component as ObjectWithProperties)[Name];
        }

        public override bool IsReadOnly
        {
            get { return false; }
        }

        public override Type PropertyType
        {
            get { return typeof(object); }
        }

        public override void ResetValue(object component)
        {
            (component as ObjectWithProperties).properties.Remove(Name);
        }

        public override void SetValue(object component, object value)
        {
            (component as ObjectWithProperties)[Name] = value;
        }

        public override bool ShouldSerializeValue(object component)
        {
            return (component as ObjectWithProperties).properties.ContainsKey(Name);
        }
    }

    Dictionary<string, object> properties = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    public object this[string name]
    {
        get
        {
            if (properties.ContainsKey(name))
            {
                return properties[name];
            }
            return null;
        }
        set
        {
            properties[name] = value;
        }
    }

    Dictionary<string, List<Attribute>> attributes = new Dictionary<string, List<Attribute>>();
    public void SetAttribute(string property, Attribute attribute)
    {
        if (attributes.ContainsKey(property))
            attributes[property].Add(attribute);
        else
            attributes[property] = new List<Attribute> { attribute };
    }


    #region ICustomTypeDescriptor Membres

    public AttributeCollection GetAttributes()
    {
        return TypeDescriptor.GetAttributes(this, true);
    }

    public string GetClassName()
    {
        return null;
    }

    public string GetComponentName()
    {
        return null;
    }

    public TypeConverter GetConverter()
    {
        return null;
    }

    public EventDescriptor GetDefaultEvent()
    {
        return null;
    }

    public PropertyDescriptor GetDefaultProperty()
    {
        return null;
    }

    public object GetEditor(Type editorBaseType)
    {
        return null;
    }

    public EventDescriptorCollection GetEvents(Attribute[] attributes)
    {
        return EventDescriptorCollection.Empty;
    }

    public EventDescriptorCollection GetEvents()
    {
        return EventDescriptorCollection.Empty;
    }

    public PropertyDescriptorCollection GetProperties(Attribute[] attributes)
    {
        return new PropertyDescriptorCollection(properties.Keys.Select(key => this.attributes.ContainsKey(key)
                ? new MyDescriptor(key, this.attributes[key].ToArray()) : new MyDescriptor(key, null)).ToArray());
    }

    public PropertyDescriptorCollection GetProperties()
    {
        return new PropertyDescriptorCollection(properties.Keys.Select(key => new MyDescriptor(key, null)).ToArray());
    }

    public object GetPropertyOwner(PropertyDescriptor pd)
    {
        return this;
    }

    //public  GetCustomAttribute(string name)
    //{
    //    var bar = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(this, new Atributos.AtributosdasPropriedades[]{})[0]; 
    //    foreach (Attribute attrib in bar.Attributes) 
    //    {
    //    } 
    //}

    #endregion
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var obj1 = new ObjectWithProperties();
        obj1["test"] = 100;
        var obj2 = new ObjectWithProperties();
        obj2["test"] = 200;
        var obj3 = new ObjectWithProperties();
        obj3["test"] = 150;

        **var obj4 = new ObjectWithProperties();
        obj4.MyProperty = 100;**

        List<ObjectWithProperties> objects = new List<ObjectWithProperties>(new ObjectWithProperties[] { obj1, obj2, obj3, obj4 });
        dataGridView1.DataSource = objects;
    }
```

As you can see, is totaly normal. but I need to show the property "MyProperty" on a gridview, with the other ones... Is that possible? Can you please give some sample showing how?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a way....

http://jopinblog.wordpress.com/category/design-patterns/

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at this 
https://web.archive.org/web/20210323170551/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/012308-1.aspx
the example if for Webcontrol Gridview , but should guide you in the right direction.